# React Redux: Useeffect calling multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to add click even listener to div based class name, here the code looks,

```
useEffect(() => {
const element = document.querySelectorAll('some-class');
element[0].addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
If(isTrigger)
{
dispatch(setIsTrigger(false))
}
else
{
dispatch(setIsTrigger(true))
}
}, [isTrigger])
```

Here trying collapse and expand div class based isTrigger value. But its calling multiple times, how to avoid it?

Can some one please help

Comment: Where does `isTrigger` come from

Comment: The `useEffect` hook appears to be updating its own dependency, which will call it in a loop. Can you provide a more [complete and comprehensive code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we've better context what this code is trying to accomplish?

Comment: @slideshowp2 isTrigger is a redux store variable

Comment: @DrewReese yeah hooks calling multiple times because of its dependency, but how can we avoid it using some logics?

Comment: It looks like you are just trying to add an event listener, attaching directly to a DOM element, or using a React ref is preferable to use `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: I think you need to provide more code so we've better context for what the code is trying to accomplish. Right now I can only suggest that maybe clicking whatever element should just dispatch a `toggleIsTrigger` action and let the reducer function correctly toggle the state. This removes needing to close over the `isToggle` value in callback scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to take redux out of the equation for a minute. Instead of redux lets assume you have this above the snippet you posted:

```
[isTrigger, setIsTrigger] = useState(false);
```

The effect is updating **isTrigger**, which is a dependency of the effect. This will cause it to go into a loop. Look below at your effect without redux:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.querySelectorAll('some-class');
    element[0].addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    if(isTrigger)
    {
        setIsTrigger(false)
    }
    else {
        setIsTrigger(true)
    }
}, [isTrigger])  // since its a dependency here, its going to get called everytime 
                 // isTrigger is updated. Since your updating it in the function, you get a loop
```

Hope this helps explain the multiple times.

As for the solving collapse/expand, do you really need the effect? Not sure how your code looks like or your redux state(I see you are using dispatch), but a possible solution:

```
const isTrigger = useSelector(selectIsTrigger);

handleClick = () => {
    dispatch(setIsTrigger(!isTrigger));
};

return (
    ... some stuff
    <div click={handleClick}></div>
)
```

I hope this helps a little at least.

Also just a note, you should also clean up after your effect since you are adding an event listener. [Effects with Cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup). You should do this when your component unmounts. By cleaning up, you'll avoid listening to events multiple times and memory leaks.

example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

  return () => document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
}, [handleClick]);
```

Comment: thanks for the code, But I still see multiple dispatchs happening in handleclick function, Is there anyway we can avoid it?

Comment: Are you able to post more of the code? That way I can see if there is another potential problem :)

Comment: Yeah useeffect looks like above you mentioned,

Comment: const handleClick = () => {dispatch(setIsTrigger(! isTrigger) ) }